# Listview in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I would like to display a list of items with columns and bind them to some custom objects of mine. There is no ListView control in Firemonkey, so what is the recommended way of doing this? I'd like the columns to be easily resizable, but don't require editable items.

Comment: Have you tried the TStringGrid?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it but the TMS FireMonkey Grid may do what you want http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=230